# Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'T'

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a Generic FindControl method and I get the following error:

**Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'T'**

Code:

```
public T Control<T>(String id)
{
  foreach (Control ctrl in MainForm.Controls.Find(id, true))
  {
    return (T)ctrl; // Form Controls have unique names, so no more iterations needed
  }

  throw new Exception("Control not found!");
}
```

Comment: What value are you passing in for `T` when you call this method?

Comment: @Jamiec: that doesn't really matter to the compiler, unless you *tell* it that `T` will always be a `Control` it can't rely on it, regardless of whether or not you always happen to be passing a `Control`...

Comment: (Off-topic:) Consider throwing an exception of a more specific type, perhaps `KeyNotFoundException` (from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace).

Comment: How come everyone who had 1 vote has been downvoted to zero? Jesus!

Comment: @Mikael Svenson: don't know about yours, but the other one was probably because of the missing `<T>`...

Comment: @David There were three answers which all had 1 vote, and suddenly they all had zero. I hope people don't down vote just to get ahead themselves. I don't know about the others, but mine was a downvote, not a "undo" vote, even though the code was correct - albeit not the first one to answer.

Comment: @Mikael Svenson: Paul was upped by me and presumably downed by leppie. I can see you've got 1up and 1dn, don't know why, but the others are complete 0s, so the other upvote you're referring to must be itay's answer, or undone. So there's 1 downvote we can't explain, that happens all the time, no reason to think it's someone who has answered here...

Comment: @David. Good reasoning. Guess we will have to live with the occasional down vote, even if it's unjustified and not commented. Thx :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
public T Control<T>(String id) where T : Control
{
  foreach (Control ctrl in MainForm.Controls.Find(id, true))
  {
    return (T)ctrl; // Form Controls have unique names, so no more iterations needed
  }

  throw new Exception("Control not found!");
}
```

Comment: As you answered first, you get the answer!

Answer (score 4):

You could always bend the rules and do a double cast. Eg:

```
public T Control<T>(String id)
{
  foreach (Control ctrl in MainForm.Controls.Find(id, true))
  {
    return (T)(object)ctrl; 
  }

  throw new Exception("Control not found!");
}
```

Comment: you could! but that's a terrible idea, considering that there's a proper way to do it

Comment: It's the only way if you deal with valuetypes or primitives. But I agree, in this instance the 'proper' way would be better.

Answer (score 1):

As T is unconstrained, you could pass anything for the type parameter.  You should add a 'where' constraint to your method signature:

```
public T Control<T>(string id) where T : Control
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling this method, have you got an example?

Also, I'd add a constraint to your method:

```
public T Control<T>(string id) where T : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While other people have already correctly pointed out what the problem is, I just want to chime in that this would be quite suitable for an extension method. Don't upvote this, this is actually a comment, I'm just posting it as an answer so that I can gain the ability to write longer and format my code better ;)

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static T FindControl<T>(this Control parent, string id) where T : Control
   {
      return item.FindControl(id) as T;
   }
}
```

So that you can invoke it like so:

```
Label myLabel = MainForm.Controls.FindControl<Label>("myLabelID");
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your method signature to this:

```
public T Control<T>(String id) where T : Control
```

Stating that all T's are in fact of type `Control`. This will constrain T and the compiler knows you can return it as T.